# QUIC server/client

Tags: c++, winapi, quic

I 've successfully used [msquic](https://github.com/microsoft/msquic) to create a simple client/server using QUIC, based on their samples.

The idea is now to create a capability of a Web client/server.  The client should be able to connect to QUIC enabled servers and the server should be able to accept connections from, say, Chrome.

For that, I 'm for example trying to connect to quic.rocks:4433 but this results in [QUIC_CONNECTION_EVENT_SHUTDOWN_INITIATED_BY_TRANSPORT](https://github.com/microsoft/msquic/blob/main/docs/api/QUIC_CONNECTION_EVENT.md) with the Status set to `ERROR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_VIOLATION`.

In my CreateConfiguration() code I'm setting a protocol:

```
QUIC_BUFFER bProtocol = { 4,(uint8_t*)"Test" };
HQUIC CreateConfiguration(PCCERT_CONTEXT pc)
{
    if (!h)
        return nullptr;
    QUIC_SETTINGS qs = {};

    if (pc)
    {
        qs.IsSet.PeerBidiStreamCount = TRUE;
        qs.PeerBidiStreamCount = 1;
    }
    HQUIC c = 0;
    st =  h->ConfigurationOpen(reg, &bProtocol, 1, &qs, sizeof(qs), this, &c);
    
    if (!c)
        return nullptr;

    QUIC_CREDENTIAL_CONFIG cfg = {};
    cfg.Type = QUIC_CREDENTIAL_TYPE_NONE;
    if (pc)
    {
        cfg.Flags = QUIC_CREDENTIAL_FLAG_NONE;
        cfg.Type = QUIC_CREDENTIAL_TYPE_CERTIFICATE_CONTEXT;
        cfg.CertificateContext = (QUIC_CERTIFICATE*)pc;
    }
    else
    {
        cfg.Flags = QUIC_CREDENTIAL_FLAG_CLIENT  | QUIC_CREDENTIAL_FLAG_NO_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION;
    }
    if (FAILED(h->ConfigurationLoadCredential(c, &cfg)))
    {
        h->ConfigurationClose(c);
        c = 0;
    }

    return c;
}
```

In my own server when I use another protocol I get also this error, so I guess it's an ALPN issue. I found in various [sources](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9114.html) that the protocol should be "h3" but even If I set that, I always get the same error.

```
QUIC_BUFFER bProtocol = { 2,(uint8_t*)"h3" };
```

Am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 0):

From previous experience, this is likely because you're not giving the server the expected number of unidirectional and bidirectional streams it wants, so it terminates the connection.

Comment: Let me check that.